# Django slug field in Arabic and other foreign languages

Tags: django, arabic

am trying to build an app with a model which contains a unique of the title, some users will write the title in Arabic and other languages and when on save, I try to slugify the field. It would return blank in case of Arabic. Any way to show arabic wordings but maintain slug principles of replacing special characters and spaces with dash?

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     if self.slug is in (None, '', u''):
       self.slug = slugify(self.title)
     super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable url encoder, simply open settings.py and at the end of file, insert as new line:

ALLOW_UNICODE_SLUGS = True

Comment: I don't see any documentation for that setting.

Answer (score 4):

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
            if not self.slug:
                self.slug = arabic_slugify(self.title)
        super(Note, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


def arabic_slugify(str):
    str = str.replace(" ", "-")
    str = str.replace(",", "-")
    str = str.replace("(", "-")
    str = str.replace(")", "")
    str = str.replace("؟", "")
    return str
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation or further details to your answer so learners can benefit from it?

Comment: God, bless you, you helped me so much

Answer (score 3):

New to Django 1.9 is the [setting `allow_unicode`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SlugField):

```
slug = SlugField(allow_unicode=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use
`allow_unicode=True` attr for each `SlugField` that you want to make it allowing Unicode.
This is s simple example:

```
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, allow_unicode=True, unique=True)
```

For the new versions of `Django` the `settings.py` `ALLOW_UNICODE_SLUGS = True` attribute will not work.

Answer (score 0):

check this https://github.com/mozilla/unicode-slugify , I have use it with Django 1.4.x/1.5.x, I was also looking for Arabic slugs.